# Android ListView Item Visibility

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a screen that displays multiples items.
For this, I've created a listview but I'm not sure how to approach how to add/remove items from it. 
Since I'm using custom listview items, I've created my own listadapter but now I need a way to add items on a button click.

Is there a way to create listview that can take an indefinite amount of items (instead of passing it in an fixed length array of View objects)? 
Also what's the best way to remove items from listviews? setVisibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new items to your data and use:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChenged();
```

You can also remove items this way

Comment: make sure to also add your adapter to the listview: listview.setAdapter(listadapter);

Answer (score 1):

when you add item  and remove item from  list then need to notify adpter so

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChenged();
```

or in List you can add no of item